# Testing unauthorized user restriction in Laravel PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

Laravel Version 5.2

In my project, users with role_id = 4 has the admin role and can manage users.

I have defined the following ability in AuthServiceProvider:

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies($gate);

    $gate->define('can-manage-users', function ($user)
    {
        return $user->role_id == 4;
    });
}
```

I have used this ability in the UserController __construct method as follows:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorize('can-manage-users');
}
```

In ExampleTest, I have created two tests to check if the defined authorization works.

The first test for admin user who has role_id = 4. This test passes.

```
public function testAdminCanManageUsers()
{
    $user = Auth::loginUsingId(1);
    $this->actingAs($user)
        ->visit('users')
        ->assertResponseOk();
}
```

The second test is for another user who does not have role_id = 4. I have tried with response status 401 and 403. But the test is failing:

```
public function testNonAdminCannotManageUsers()
{
    $user = Auth::loginUsingId(4);
    $this->actingAs($user)
        ->visit('users')
        ->assertResponseStatus(403);
}
```

First few lines of the failure message is given below:

> A request to [http://localhost/users] failed. Received status code [403].
>
> C:\wamp\www\laravel\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:196
>   C:\wamp\www\laravel\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:80
>   C:\wamp\www\laravel\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:61
>   C:\wamp\www\laravel\blog\tests\ExampleTest.php:33
>
> Caused by exception 'Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException'
>   with message 'This action is unauthorized.' in
>   C:\wamp\www\laravel\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization.php:28

I have also tried to use 'see' method as follows:

```
public function testNonAdminCannotManageUsers()
{
    $user = Auth::loginUsingId(4);
    $this->actingAs($user)
        ->visit('users')
        ->see('This action is unauthorized.');
}
```

But it's failing too. What am I doing wrong? How can I make the test pass?

Comment: Any advance on this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mistake is calling the `visit` method. The `visit` method is in the `InteractsWithPages` trait. This method calls the `makeRequest` method which in turn calls `assertPageLoaded` method. This method gets the status code returned and if it gets code other than 200, it catches a `PHPUnitException` and throws an `HttpException` with the message

> "A request to [{$uri}] failed. Received status code [{$status}]."

This is why the test was failing with the above message.

The test can be successfully passed by using `get` method instead of `visit` method. For example:

```
public function testNonAdminCannotManageUsers()
{
    $user = App\User::where('role_id', '<>', 4)->first();

    $this->actingAs($user)
        ->get('users')
        ->assertResponseStatus(403);
}
```

This test will pass and confirm that a non admin user cannot access the url.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Auth` middleware redirects to a login route when unauthenticated by default you could also perform the following test:

```php
public function testNonAdminCannotManageUsers()
{
    $user = Auth::loginUsingId(4);
    $this->actingAs($user)
        ->visit('users')
        ->assertRedirect('login');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since at least Laravel 5.4, you'll want to use the `assertStatus(403)` method.

```
public function testNonAdminCannotManageUsers()
{
    $user = Auth::loginUsingId(4);
    $this->actingAs($user)
        ->visit('users')
        ->assertStatus(403);
}
```